# How do I reject an integer from being used during user input?

Tags: arrays, c, string

I am a working on a program that takes multiple strings and outputs them by printing every other character in the word. However, I want to reject the input if its anything other than a string. So basically if the user tries to enter a 2 ,or any integer really, I want it to ask for input again. Or just simply not accept it. Here is what I have so far. I've only been programming for a week so go easy on me...

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{   //Declare an array
    char str[100];
    //Get input from user    
    scanf("%s", str);
    //Loop that prints even characters
    for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
    if(i % 2 == 0)
    {
        printf("%c", str[i]);
    }
    }   //Space between even/odd characters
        printf(" ");
    //Loop that prints odd characters    
    for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
    if(i % 2 != 0)
    {
        printf("%c", str[i]);
    
    }
    }
        printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "However, I want to reject the input if its anything other than a string." What's your definition of a string? Is "abc123" a string? If so, why is "98" not a string?

Comment: What about an input like `1.234`? Should that be accepted or rejected?

Comment: In this example I would call words a string and numbers integers. So only accept abc... and reject any 123. This would go for all variations as well, no doubles, no floats, etc..

Answer (score 0):

the problem can be solved with a control function like below. When unwanted values are entered, the input can be taken again or those values can be eliminated from the entered string.
`

```
bool control(char currentChar);

int main()
{
char str[100];
bool controlNumeric = false;

while(controlNumeric == false)
{
    scanf("%s", str);
    for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        controlNumeric = control(str[i]);
        if(controlNumeric == false)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
{
    if(i % 2 == 0)
    {
        printf("%c", str[i]);
    }
    }   //Space between even/odd characters
        printf(" ");

    for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
    if(i % 2 != 0)
    {
        printf("%c", str[i]);
    }
}
    printf("\n");
return 0;
}

bool control(char currentChar)
{
switch(currentChar)
{
    case '0': 
    case '1': 
    case '2': 
    case '3': 
    case '4': 
    case '5': 
    case '6':
    case '7': 
    case '8': 
    case '9': 
        return false;
        break;
    default:
        return false;
        break;
}
return true;
}`
```

Comment: Thanks Kemal!. I thought at first I could do it with a do while loop but dont have the knowledge of all the operators.  I tried running the code and am unable to compile so far. Out of curiosity, what are the case numbers for at the bottom?

Comment: @Kemal Bayram: control function always returns false

Comment: `scanf("%s", str);` better as `scanf("%99s", str);` is avoid overrun.

Comment: Hello, the numbers in the 'case' represent all possible numeric values. If any of them matches the entered value, it means that the man entered spam.

Comment: I am also sharing this answer so that you can make it easier while(controlNumeric == false){
            scanf("%s", str);
        
            for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++){
                if(isdigit(str[i])){
                    controlNumeric = false;
                    break;
                }
                else{
                    controlNumeric = true;
                }
            }
        }